# Rails app works but feature spec fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a self-join relation on a User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :students, class_name:  "User",
                        foreign_key: "teacher_id"
  belongs_to :teacher,  class_name:  "User"
end
```

I have a students controller:

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @students = current_user.students
  end

end
```

The corresponding view for the index method looks like this:

```
%ul#students-list
  - @students.each do |student|
    %li= student.full_name
```

As you would expect I can see a list of students when I navigate to `/students`. Yay!

**However**, my feature spec written in Capybara fails.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Navigating to students" do
  let!(:teacher) { create(:teacher_user) }
  let!(:student) { create(:student_user, teacher: teacher) }

  before do
    login_as teacher
    visit '/students'
  end

  it "displays a list of students" do
    expect(page).to have_selector('ul#students-list li')
  end

end
```

Here are my factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :teacher_user, class: "User" do
    email
    password "asterisk"
    first_name "James"
    last_name "Baldwin"
    association :user_type, factory: :user_type_teacher
  end

  factory :student_user, class: "User" do
    email
    password "asterisk"
    first_name "Yuri"
    last_name "Kochiyama"
    association :user_type, factory: :user_type_student
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you know that the page is loading correctly? Try adding `expect(page.status_code).to eq 200`. You could also add `expect(teacher.students).to include student` to ensure that your data is being setup correctly.

Comment: also make sure that your factory is actually working and not silently failing

Comment: @Luke The later test you suggest fails because the `teacher.students` is a CollectionProxy. I'm not sure what to make of that.

Comment: @TMP I think the factories are okay. I inspected what was in the database with byebug and it appears everything is getting created.

Comment: @niftygrifty What about `expect(teacher.students.to_a).to include student`?

Comment: @Luke Hmm... it appears that array is empty so the data must not be set up right. Looking at it in Byebug I can see that the relation `teacher.students` returns nil, but `student.teacher` works. So the inverse doesn't work? Does this have something to do with the self join?

Comment: @niftygrifty I don't think it's self-join specific. Try adding `inverse_of` to your association declarations: `has_many :students, inverse_of: :teacher`, `belongs_to :teacher, inverse_of: :students`.

Comment: @niftygrifty http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html Cmd-F "inverse_of"

Comment: I noticed that earlier. But adding `inverse_of` doesn't make the spec pass either.. :/

Comment: If I use `:rack_test` instead of Selenium, all works fine. I would love to hear more thoughts on all this.

Comment: They probably have different implementations of `have_selector`. I don't know why yours would act differently on each though.